# How can I put a background in my setup with nsis?

Tags: installation, nsis

I'm creating a `setup.exe` to my application and I'm using the [nsis](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) setup creator and I am compiling on ubuntu.

Now I want customize the setup to appear with background image like this:

[image: nsis setup]

How can I put a background in my setup with [nsis](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)?

Comment: Why are you compiling a setup.exe for windows on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A clue would be, editing the required UI executable using Resource hacker and add a picture control on top of it.

You can find the available UI modules inside system path:
C:\Program Files\NSIS\Contrib\UIs.

Then once you are done with your editing, define the custom UI using !define MUI_UI in your script and process accordingly.

Comment: Ok I follow your setps but how I can put this picture on backgroud?

Comment: @JorgeB.: Please have a look at the below posted Answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your picture is actually this one: http://www.graphical-installer.com/joomla/images/stories/gallery/projects/gallery-4.jpg

So you can use that software - **Graphical Installer for NSIS** - to achieve exactly the same effect without any effort or programming :)

As author of that software I can say it is really easy to achieve such design:

1. Add custom control on installer UI (using ResHacker) - the better is to create new UI file so your previous installer will not be corrupted
2. Load image from file into control - use WinAPI calls or some NSIS wrapper. Keep in mind the picture path must be somewhere on end-user's computer, e.g. $Temp.

(the same as *hypheni* said but with more details)

Answer (score 2):

For more details please refer to the below code snippet

```
Var hBitmap
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT CustomGUIInit

Function CustomGUIInit
    InitPluginsDir
    ReserveFile `${BMP_HEAD}`
    File `/ONAME=$PLUGINSDIR\head.bmp` `${BMP_HEAD}`

    GetDlgItem $R1 $HWNDPARENT 1034
    System::Call `user32::LoadImage(i 0, t "$PLUGINSDIR\head.bmp", i ${IMAGE_BITMAP}, i 0, i 0, i ${LR_LOADFROMFILE}) i.s`
    Pop $hBitmap
    SendMessage $R1 ${STM_SETIMAGE} ${IMAGE_BITMAP} $hBitmap
FunctionEnd
```

The above code is calling LoadImage Win32 API function from user32.dll and sets to windows control by SendMessage call.

Comment: @JorgeB.: You wil have to check 'GetDlgItem $R1 $HWNDPARENT 1034', Image paths.

Comment: what do you mean? I am new at this and I'm struggling to see the logic of that

Comment: You need to understand LoadImage, SendMessage API of windows. Otherwise you won't be able to understand the above code. Its better to start off with Google and MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

add yourimage : res.bmp near to script.

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"

; Local bitmap path.
!define BITMAP_FILE res.bmp

; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Installer Settings
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name "Background Bitmap"
OutFile "bgbitmap.exe"
ShowInstDetails show
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE # this is responsible for the big window
;!define MUI_UI_HEADERIMAGE ".\dimm_beta_img.exe" # modded exe
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Modern UI Settings
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!define MUI_COMPONENTSPAGE_NODESC
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_NOAUTOCLOSE
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT MyGUIInit

; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Definitions
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Var hBitmap

; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Pages
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW WelcomePageShow
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Macros
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Destroy a window.
!macro DestroyWindow HWND IDC
GetDlgItem $R0 ${HWND} ${IDC}
System::Call `user32::DestroyWindow(i R0)`
!macroend

; Give window transparent background.
!macro SetTransparent HWND IDC
GetDlgItem $R0 ${HWND} ${IDC}
SetCtlColors $R0 0x444444 transparent
!macroend

; Refresh window.
!macro RefreshWindow HWND IDC
GetDlgItem $R0 ${HWND} ${IDC}
ShowWindow $R0 ${SW_HIDE}
ShowWindow $R0 ${SW_SHOW}
!macroend

; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Functions
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function MyGUIInit
; Extract bitmap image.
InitPluginsDir
ReserveFile `${BITMAP_FILE}`
File `/ONAME=$PLUGINSDIR\res.bmp` `${BITMAP_FILE}`
; Get the size of the window.
System::Call `*${stRECT} .R0`
System::Call `user32::GetClientRect(i $HWNDPARENT, i R0)`
System::Call `*$R0${stRECT} (, , .R1, .R2)`
System::Free $R0
; Create bitmap control.
System::Call `kernel32::GetModuleHandle(i 0) i.R3`
System::Call `user32::CreateWindowEx(i 0, t "STATIC", t "", i ${SS_BITMAP}|${WS_CHILD}|${WS_VISIBLE}, i 0, i 0, i R1, i R2, i $HWNDPARENT, i ${IDC_BITMAP}, i R3, i 0) i.R1`
System::Call `user32::SetWindowPos(i R1, i ${HWND_TOP}, i 0, i 0, i 0, i 0, i ${SWP_NOSIZE}|${SWP_NOMOVE})`
; Set the bitmap.
System::Call `user32::LoadImage(i 0, t "$PLUGINSDIR\res.bmp", i ${IMAGE_BITMAP}, i 0, i 0, i ${LR_CREATEDIBSECTION}|${LR_LOADFROMFILE}) i.s`
Pop $hBitmap
SendMessage $R1 ${STM_SETIMAGE} ${IMAGE_BITMAP} $hBitmap
; Set transparent backgrounds.
!insertmacro SetTransparent $HWNDPARENT 3
!insertmacro SetTransparent $HWNDPARENT 1
!insertmacro SetTransparent $HWNDPARENT 2
!insertmacro SetTransparent $HWNDPARENT 1034
!insertmacro SetTransparent $HWNDPARENT 1037
!insertmacro SetTransparent $HWNDPARENT 1038
!insertmacro SetTransparent $HWNDPARENT 1028
!insertmacro SetTransparent $HWNDPARENT 1256
; !insertmacro SetTransparent $HWNDPARENT 1045
!insertmacro SetTransparent $HWNDPARENT 1035
; Remove unwanted controls.
!insertmacro DestroyWindow $HWNDPARENT 1256
!insertmacro DestroyWindow $HWNDPARENT 1028
; !insertmacro DestroyWindow $HWNDPARENT 1039
!insertmacro DestroyWindow $HWNDPARENT 1045 # dimm remove line from bottom
; !insertmacro DestroyWindow $HWNDPARENT 1035
; !insertmacro DestroyWindow $HWNDPARENT 1256
FunctionEnd

Function RefreshParentControls
!insertmacro RefreshWindow $HWNDPARENT 1037
!insertmacro RefreshWindow $HWNDPARENT 1038
FunctionEnd

Function WelcomePageShow
# Sets background image
System::Call `user32::LoadImage(i 0, t "$PLUGINSDIR\res.bmp", i ${IMAGE_BITMAP}, i 0, i 0, i ${LR_CREATEDIBSECTION}|${LR_LOADFROMFILE}) i.s`
Pop $hBitmap
; SendMessage $bitmapWindow ${STM_SETIMAGE} ${IMAGE_BITMAP} $hBitmap
# Start solution
SetCtlColors $mui.WelcomePage ${CTRL_COLOUR} transparent
SetCtlColors $mui.WelcomePage.text ${CTRL_COLOUR} transparent
SetCtlColors $mui.WelcomePage.title 0x333333 transparent
!insertmacro DestroyWindow $HWNDPARENT 1037
!insertmacro DestroyWindow $HWNDPARENT 1038
!insertmacro DestroyWindow $HWNDPARENT 1036
SetCtlColors $0 222425 transparent
System::Call `user32::DestroyWindow(i $mui.WelcomePage.Image)`

Call RefreshParentControls
FunctionEnd
; BrandingText ""

; Free loaded resources.
Function .onGUIEnd
; Destroy the bitmap.
System::Call `gdi32::DeleteObject(i s)` $hBitmap
FunctionEnd

; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Dummy section
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Section "Dummy Section"
SectionEnd
```